# Loading classes in run time with spl_autoload_register will result in poor performance?

Tags: php

Well if i do something like:

boot.php:

```
function boot($c) { require 'mods/'.$c.'.php'; }
spl_autoload_register('boot');
```

index.php

```
require 'boot.php';

class Father {
function __construct()
{
/* get all modules in database then loop it like: */
foreach($mods as $v) eval('$cmod = new '.$v.'()');
}
}
new Father();
```

Example of a class module:

```
class mod01 extends Father {

function __construct() { //code }

}
```

I would like to know if use eval is a good or bad point, i'm using it cuz i don't know the name of mods it will come of db.

Comment: I use `spl_autoload_register()` without noticing poor performance

Comment: no need to do `eval` you can just do `$class = 'Father'; new $class();` or in your case you can just do: `$cmod = new $v();`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Scream.jpg - It's probably eval() that's causing the slowdown: using eval() in this situation is just bad

Comment: @MarkBaker don't know, I think it's more that all these single files have to be loaded...

Comment: I don't really see the point of using an autoloader, and then loading every class file whether it's needed or not... surely the whole point of an autoloader is only loading files when it's needful

Comment: @MarkBaker autoloader… we don't have to manually include the files?

Comment: in this case calling new className inside the Father class, i still can access variables of Father class in these sub classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need `eval()`. (and if not necessary, simply don't use it)

```
foreach($mods as $v)
    $cmod = new $v();
```

Works too.

Comment: in this case calling new className inside the Father class, i still can access variables of Father class in these sub classes?

Comment: not automatically. You have to pass $this as a parameter to the constructor. (same with eval()) (and save the parameter in property to access the contents of Father class)

Comment: but if i pass $this as parameter on constructor, why then should i extends to father class? i.e: class mod01 extends Father

Comment: i mean if i'll pass the $this on construct then i don't need to extends these sub classes isn't?

Comment: @FredGustavo in the class: `class newclass { protected $father; public function __construct (Father $father) { $this->father = $father; } public function someMethod() { /* do something with $this->father (points to your father instance if you have passed $this */ } }`

Comment: I understand but i rly need to pass the $this on construct since i extended the class? or i only need to do it cuz i'm calling the class insinde another class?

Comment: @FredGustavo yes, you don't need to extend it, but you need to pass $this. As this would be two different instances of Father class.

Comment: @bwoedi hum, but these mods are 'is a' Father, then should i extends,isn't? i mean about writting the properly oop

Comment: @FredGustavo maybe, I don't know your whole program and I don't want to know it … And as this answer seems to have solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green bordered tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it either way and still have access to the newly created classes.

```
$classes = array() ;
foreach($mods as $v){
  $classes[] = new $v(); //Whats the point of rewriting $cmod?
}
```

You just rewrite reference to objects in each iteration, so store your references in an array.